# How to set up neo4j-java-driver and gremlin-scala in scala

Tags: scala, neo4j

I have neo4j-community-3.5.5, scala 2.11.8 and Idea 2018.3.4 community version.

I tried 2 methods to access Neo4j database with scala but neither works yet.

1. I followed suggestion [here](https://blog.knoldus.com/getting-started-neo4j-with-scala-an-introduction/)  and have this library dependency in build.sbt.

   ```
   libraryDependencies += "org.neo4j.driver" % "neo4j-java-driver" % "1.0.4"
   ```

But `GraphDatabase` below is not recognized. Am I missing any import?

```
val driver = GraphDatabase.driver("bolt://localhost/7474", 
  AuthTokens.basic("username", "password"))
val session = driver.session
```

2. I followed suggestion [here](https://github.com/mpollmeier/gremlin-scala) and have this library dependency in build.sbt

   ```
   libraryDependencies += "com.michaelpollmeier" %% "gremlin-scala" % "3.4.1.4"
   ```

But scala does not recognize `tinkergraph`. What I am missing and is there a link describing how to set it up?

```
import gremlin.scala._
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.tinkergraph.structure.TinkerFactory
```

Comment: sometimes you have to refresh the project for dependencies to load, did you try run it again with sbt / sbt clean and so on?

Comment: Yes I tried them after even restarting Idea and with only one dependeny of question in sbt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For neo4j-java-driver I missed the following import to make it work. A more complete list of import you need can be found [here](https://www.cnblogs.com/gmhappy/p/9472432.html).

```
import org.neo4j.driver.v1.{AuthTokens,GraphDatabase}
```

Haven't got any response from the owner of Gremlin yet on Github.